# Help me calculate this integral.$ f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f:(0,1) \rightarrow \Bbb R, f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}$ I tried to write the integral as $f(x)=(-\frac{1}{x})'\arcsin x$. Following this idea(I integrated by parts) I get stuck at $\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}dx$. PLEASE HELP

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ should be in the denominator.

Comment: I splitted $\int \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ in two separate fractions and thus i obtained one fraction with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ as the denominator and one with it as nominator

Comment: Does this supplementary step simplify something?

Comment: I dont think so...

Comment: $\frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}$ is not integrable over $(0,1)$ since it behaves like $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Apparently the OP is interested in the antiderivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good:
$$
\int\frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}\,dx=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}+\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
$$
Now do $2u=\arcsin x$, with $x=\sin 2u$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos 2u$ and $dx=2\cos 2u\,du$:
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=
\int\frac{1}{\sin 2u\cos 2u}2\cos 2u\,du=\int\frac{1}{\sin u\cos u}\,du
$$
With just $x=\sin u$ we'd get $1/\sin u$ as the integrand, which is usually done with $u=2v$, so it's simpler to jump over it. The integral is computed by noting that $1=\cos^2u+\sin^2u$, so we have
$$
\int\left(\frac{\cos u}{\sin u}+\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\right)du=
\log\lvert\sin u\rvert-\log\lvert\cos u\rvert+c
$$
Actually, no absolute value is needed. Since
$$
\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}=\frac{2\sin^2u}{2\sin u\cos u}=\frac{1-\cos2u}{\sin2u}
$$
we finally arrive at the antiderivative
$$
-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}+\log\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x^2}dx$$
$x=\sin(u)$ so $dx=\cos(u)du$
$$I=\int\frac{u}{\sin^2(u)}du=\int u\csc^2(u)du=-u\cot(u)+\int\cot(u)du$$
Now you should be able to easily finish this

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $\sqrt{1-x^2}=y\implies x\ dx=-y\ dy,x^2=1-y^2$

$\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=x\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}$

Alternatively, set $x=\sin t,-\dfrac\pi2\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\sin^2t=1-\cos^2t,\cos t=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$